# How to remove these "special characters" from MySQL results?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

In the database I'm using, some of the pieces are formatted like this

```
S    1    A    1
```

Is there any function to remove the characters and format my result as just

```
S1A1
```

to clean this up? Notepad++ shows the characters are `SOH` (Start of Header). Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SOH` is ASCII code 1, so you can use

```
REPLACE(columnname, CHAR(1), '')
```

to remove them from the value.